# how to get all the value option of price navigation using code in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i have requirement to get all the sub option of the price navigation sort by sub option in magneto using coding because i need that on the top of category product listing page

For example show below image

[image]

in navigation left side filter there are three option list i need that option using coding because i am creating custom navigation filter on product listing toolbar top in magneto 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change position of price filter range than change in below code

```
admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes -> Price
```

change position of price attribute

Comment: sorry Dhaval Patel but  posion of the  left side navigation is perfact but  i would like to get sub option and use in above product listing page.thanks

Answer (score 0):

try below link code for custom layer

```
http://inchoo.net/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/

https://prafulrajput.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/how-to-show-custom-collection-with-layered-navigation-in-magento/
```